# String not showing in TextArea from TextField

Tags: java, swing, listener, documentlistener

I am making a simple GUI for checking my string spellings and want to show text continuously, So what i am write in text field it continuously updating text area for this i have used Document listener for that but i have a problem i am unable to show a text from input field in a text Area through my defined String like

```
String check = input.getText();

textarea.setText(check);
```

I wonder why it didn't work, However i am able to use this method to work properly

```
//String check = input.getText();

textarea.setText(input.getText());
```

I want to use the first method for preprocessing my String for my spell check

Help me about this !

Working Method:

```
public void setText()
    {

        jTextArea1.setEditable(false);

        input.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                jTextArea1.setText(input.getText());

            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                jTextArea1.setText(input.getText());

            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            //Plain text components don't fire these events.
            }
        });
    }
```

Non Working MEthod:

```
public void setText()
    {

        jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
       String check = input.getText();
        input.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                jTextArea1.setText(check);

            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                jTextArea1.setText(check);

            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            //Plain text components don't fire these events.
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: There should be no difference. Are you perhaps trying to set `check` somewhere else than in the document listener?

Comment: Can you please post the whole method. As kiheru said, this should work fine.

Comment: Yes it seems no difference but it just didnt show my text  :( I dont know why

Comment: There's a fundamental difference: the latter version gets the text outside the document listener. That value *does not change*, just because `getText()` would later return a different value. Strings are immutable, and the `check` keeps referring to the same string as you originally set it to.

Comment: What should i do now ?

Comment: Use the working version. That's the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem with an inputKeyTyped listener and an inputFocusLost listener:

```
    private void inputKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

         String s;
         s = input.getText();
         output.setText(s);

    }

    private void inputFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                

         String s;
         s = input.getText();
         output.setText(s);

    }
```

In my test application, it works fine. After every typed letter the output updates. (First textfield is called "input", the second "output").

[image]

Comment: you also used ' output.setText(input.getText()); " I want this to work " output.setText(s); " Where "s" is a string which have a value of user input